# In open cv, how can i convert gray scale image back in to RGB image(color)

Tags: c++, image, opencv

In open cv to remove background, using current frame and former frame, i applied absdiff function and created a difference image in gray scale. However, i would like to covert the gray scale image back in to RGB with actual color of the image, but i have no idea how to operate this back in.
I'm using C++.
Could any one knowledgeable of open cv help me?

Comment: Sounds like "how can I make my 'mono' audio recording back into stereo" . You have lost the colour information, it is no longer there, you can't know what is red, green or blue, just the intensity is left.

Comment: Well, you have your original image, don't you? So, use the greyscale image to create a "mask", and then remove the areas you don't want, apply mask to the original image.

Comment: then is their any way that i can extract color from the original image before operating absdiff function

Comment: So, use the greyscale image to create a "mask", and then remove the areas you don't want, apply mask to the original image. (No, I don't know the exact functionality in OpenCV that does this, but I'm sure it's possible)

Comment: thans sooooooo much. It was such a helpful hint!!!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot covert the gray scale image back into RGB with actual color of the image again as coverting RGB to gray scale is a data-losing process.

Instead, as @MatsPetersson suggested, you can take the use of the grayscale image to create a mask, e.g. by further applying a [thresholding process](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=threshold#threshold). Then you can easily get the ROI color image by:

```
cv::Mat dst;
src.copyTo(dst, mask);
```

Comment: thanks...i finally got some hope of solving this issue